# Check how many times a string is inside a string

Tags: javascript

I got this string:

```
var longText="This is a superuser test, super user is is super important!";
```

I want to know how many times the string "su" is in longText and the position of each "su".

I was trying with:

```
var nr4 = longText.replace("su", "").length;
```

And the difference of lenght between the main text and the nr4 divided by "su" lenght beeing 2 is resulting a number of repetitions but i bet there is a better way of doing it.

Comment: `var howmany=longText.split("su").length` or `var res =longtext.match(/su/g);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example

```
var parts=longText.split("su");
alert(parts.length-1); // length will be two if there is one "su"
```

More details using [exec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec)

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/p7v8k63x/)

```
var re =/su/g, pos=[];
while ((result = re.exec(longText)) !== null) {
  pos.push(result.index);
}
if (pos.length>0) alert(pos.length+" found at "+pos.join(","));
```

---

[image]

Comment: ok thats working so far, and how can i check the position of each "su"?

Comment: "su".split("su").length = 2

Answer (score 1):

Use [`exec`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec). Example amended from the MDN code. `len` contains the number of times `su` appears.

```
var myRe = /su/g;
var str = "This is a superuser test, super user is is super important!";
var myArray, len = 0;
while ((myArray = myRe.exec(str)) !== null) {
  len++;
  var msg = "Found " + myArray[0] + ".  ";
  msg += "Next match starts at " + myRe.lastIndex;
  console.log(msg, len);
}

// "Found su.  Next match starts at 12" 1
// "Found su.  Next match starts at 28" 2
// "Found su.  Next match starts at 45" 3
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/gyz0p9zv/)

Answer (score 0):

Could do :

```
var indexesOf = function(baseString, strToMatch){

    var baseStr = new String(baseString);

    var wordLen = strToMatch.length;
    var listSu = [];
    // Number of strToMatch occurences
    var nb = baseStr.split(strToMatch).length - 1;

    for (var i = 0, len = nb; i < len; i++){
        var ioF = baseStr.indexOf(strToMatch);
        baseStr = baseStr.slice(ioF + wordLen, baseStr.length);
        if (i > 0){
            ioF = ioF + listSu[i-1] + wordLen;
        }
        listSu.push(ioF);
    }
    return listSu;
}

indexesOf("This is a superuser test, super user is is super important!","su");
return [10, 26, 43]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var longText="This is a superuser test, super user is is super important!";
var count = 0;
while(longText.indexOf("su") != -1) { // NB the indexOf() method is case sensitive!
    longText = longText.replace("su",""); //replace first occurence of 'su' with a void string
    count++;
}
```

Comment: Destructive method is not recommended.